# Why is IE8 ignoring the background color?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

We have a site here and it displays a white background correctly in all modern browsers, Ie9-11,Chrome,FF,Safari, etc. However, OF COURSE, IE 8 messes it up and seems to make a transparent background and I have no idea why. This is also on the news page only so I'm wondering if it has to do with the horrible tables-based layout SharePoint is using (I'm not a fan). [Here's the URL](http://pipnee.com/P1155726D).

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

Comment: @MrLister not sure who that is, but the color code #DeltaPlaceHolderMain .container {background: #ffffff;} code is the same in both pages. I tried some things on the custom stylesheet for just the news page to see if it fixed it, but no changes.

Answer (score 0):

It's not about IE, it's about `html`. My guess is that IE is in the Quirks Mode (as are all the browsers) because you have a leftover closing comment close to your `doctype`. Correct it.

P.s. All the new browsers have to arrange the code by themselves too. If you inspect the site and look into the DOM you'll see that instead of the `<head>` all your `link`s and `meta`s are in the `<body>`.

Comment: I can't control SharePoint's messy output. It really is crap. But I can confirm with the IE 8 dev tools it is using IE 8 Standards mode. The main site (Home) link displays fine in IE 8. The News page (linked) does not. The only difference I think is the tables.

Comment: Yes, it will look good, because the homepage does not have `<span id="DeltaSPWebPartManager"></span>` in the `head`, and uses proper conditional comments close to the `doctype`. If you can't control your html - I wonder where you get those fancy `meta`s and `links`

Comment: I am seeing the meta and links in the head already. Also, here's the code that generates that span I guess. It's the exact same (in the head tag) for both masterpages (home and the news site).

`<SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaSPWebPartManager" runat="server">
            <WebPartPages:SPWebPartManager runat="server">
            </WebPartPages:SPWebPartManager>
        </SharePoint:AjaxDelta>`